# Glyph coverage for Unicode characters in various OS

Tags: html, unicode

When creating a web page, not all unicode characters are always available across default installation of various operating systems. Mostly because lack of fonts, or problematic fallback font system.

See for example, [this presentation](http://98.245.80.27/tcpc/OSCON2011/gbu/gbu.html) has many missing character in chrome on default Windows 7 installation.

Is there a `caniuse.com`-like website for unicode fonts availability?

(Yes, it's always possible to embed free font in your document a la

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Symbola';
  src: url(
      'https://github.com/laughinghan/mathquill/blob/master/font/Symbola.ttf?raw=true'
      );
}
body {font-family: 'Symbola';}
</style>
</header>
<body>

<h1>&#x263b; &#x26ad; &#x26ae; &#x26af;</h1>

<p>&#x2680; &#x2681; &#x2682; &#x2683;
   &#x2684; &#x2685; &#x2686; &#x2398;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

but you might want your website to work without prior `870k` font fetched, or you want it to work with email, or older browsers, etc)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "unicode symbol", or as "available" for that matter. Please phrase your question more carefully.

Comment: Unicode in fact has a category of symbol characters, but indeed characters are more exact. I rephrased the body of the question, but How do you suggest to phrase the title? "Which unicode characters will not be displayed in your browser because your default fonts are missing, or because fallback mechanism didn't work"? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/index.htm

Comment: I'd suggest something involving the terms "glyph coverage for Unicode characters in common fonts", or something along those lines.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Thanks. Let me know if you have other suggestion to improve the question, and I'll appreciate it if you can remove the downvote. (Of course you can edit them in yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t thin there is any site of the caniuse.com type for characters; it would be a rather large site, and maintaining it would be a nightmare. I quickly souped up a short section “Which characters can I use” that I added to my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html), but it’s really just a few hints.

The good news is that nowadays the issue is mostly font support to characters, and this can often be handled by setting up a suitable `font-family` list in CSS. Browsers cannot always pick up a character from a font unless the web page author gives a helping hand that way.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia uses

```
.IPA, .Unicode {
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
```

Since you want to display arbitrary Unicode characters, using those fonts would be the only option. You might want to include Lucida Grande to cater to Mac, as suggested at http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

```
.IPA, .Unicode {
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande";
}
```

Then ensure that the characters you use are present in those fonts. You can find out using charmap.exe

Answer (score 0):

> you want it to work with email, or older browsers, etc

That basically eleiminates the use of webfonts.

The problem of course is that you don't know which fonts are installed on the user's system. Even though 99% of Windows users have the [Core fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web) installed, that need not be true for Linux users. That being said, fileformat.info has a [coverage list for each individual character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/fontsupport.htm), but I haven't seen anything like caniuse.com for fonts.

Comment: FWIW, this is an attempt to list commonly available fonts: http://www.webmasterpro.de/coding/article/css-verbreitung-von-schriften-im-webdesign-tabelle.html (it's in German and dates back to 2009, but I guess it's still useful)

Comment: you do know which default fonts there are on each system, and you can make your choices according to this information (ie, `U+06CC` would work in Linux Mac and Win7, but not on XP). Just like `caniuse.com` does.

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer would be:

font-family: "Arial Unicode MS","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande","unifont_upper", "unifont";

I have added here the GNU "unifont", which is present on all Linux systems by default. Also, "unifont_upper" has glyphs even beyond Unicode's Basic Multilingual Plane, referred to as "Supplemental Multilingual Plane".

---

references for GNU unifont:

https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/unifont/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont